# Guitar amp modeler monitoring problems with high stage volume

Tags: monitor, guitar-rig

I have a Kemper Stage guitar amp modeler with a Line 6 Powercab FRFR monitor that I use only in flat mode for practice at home and as a monitor at church. When at church, the Powercab is on the floor of the stage, next to me, and pointed towards my head. A goal being to hear myself while minimizing impact to the stage and house sound. Everything is great at home, and I keep things at pretty low volumes. However, when I’m at church and using the amp as a monitor I run into problems when the stage volume is high. Most noticeably it’s when there are horns that are blasting a section of the music. It’s then that I can’t hear myself. I then try to turn my amp up, and I notice I’m unpleasantly surprised with boomy bass. I’m really just trying to cut through the mix without the boomy bass (also don't want to blow a speaker). Maybe I’m just looking for high end, though I’m not really sure how to best articulate what I’m looking for.

I’ve thought about turning down the bass knob on the Kemper, but I don’t think I want to affect the house sound at all. My hope for the Kemper was to give the house mixers a good amp sound, and let them control volume, equalizer, etc on their end, and control my monitor the way I want it. Though, I wonder if I’m getting overly loud bass with the Powercab loud, then maybe they’re getting the same thing.

Does anyone have any experience with this kind of thing, and have any solutions or recommendations? I’m open to anything. Thanks!

Comment: Is the amp on the floor/stage, or elevated?

Comment: @Tetsujin on the floor/stage

Comment: All I can think is to a) talk to the FoH crew & b) try it on a chair. Maybe you're either running too much bass for FoH, in which case they'll be glad you asked, or you're stuck in some bad resonant bass-trap so only you can hear it.